# What is the optimum file size for django error log. Does the large fiel size cause slowness of server?

Tags: django

The httpd server is taking 100% cpu. My log file size is 747 mB. Can this be the reason for high CPU usage?

Comment: Normally it should not slow the process down: the logger is a file handler, and thus the file size should have (close to) no impact on the writing time (at least not on modern file systems). Can you see what process is taking the CPU cycles (with `top`)?

Comment: PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                                                  
100430 XXXXX    20   0 10.5g 346m 6920 S 100.0  0.1   4762:19 httpd